# Find upright bounding rectangle of the intersection of two circles

Tags: geometry

[image: upright bounding rectangle of the intersection of two circles]
I want to find a minimal upright rectangle that bounds a set described by two overlapping circles, marked red in the figure, shaded in.

The circles are defined in terms of a center points and radius: $C_1(x_1, y_1, r_1)$; $C_2(x_2, y_2, r_2)$. The circles are not guaranteed to intersect, but they're guaranteed to have a non-zero common area, that is, they're either intersecting, or one contained within the other.
I understand that the rectangle that I'm looking for can be expressed as a combination of two other rectangles - intersection of two individual upright bounding rectangles, marked black, and one formed by the two points of intersection (if such exist), marked blue. The problem is that I'm not sure how combine then, since I don't know in advance how the circles are oriented.

I am looking for an analytical way to derive the solution, without relying on visual intuition. The first figure is just an example, here is another with a different configuration:
[image: figure2]

Comment: Are you able to compute the coordinates of the intersection points (if they exist)?

Comment: Can the rectangle be tilted?

Comment: @Moti no, its sides have to be parallel/normal to axes

Comment: @user yes, they define the second, blue rectangle

Comment: The sides of the required triangle are along the tangents to the sides of the circle - look at left and right and up and down with the centers as reference.

Comment: @Moti Depending on how the circles are oriented, they could could be along the tangents, but it's not always the case. In my figure the top side and the right side are along the tangents, but left and bottom aren't (although bottom might be difficult to see). Here the left and bottom sides are defined by the two intersection points. In other cases left and right could be defined by intersections while top and bottom by the tangents etc. I'm looking for an analytic way to determine the solution, without relying on visual intuition.

Comment: Right. So, back to the question in the first comment, which you haven’t yet answered: do you know how to compute the intersection points? There will be four cases to consider based on the number of intersections and their relative positions.

Comment: @amd "@user yes, they define the second, blue rectangle"

Comment: In that case, compute them. You can then essentially trim the smaller circle’s bounding box based on where the two circle centers lie relative to those intersections.

Comment: Use center of circles as reference. Calculate intersection or tangent circles. use x's and y's to find the inclusion of points. Start with verifying that there is such rectangle. It requires some work...